# Autenticação roteador

Tags: c++, socket, router

Estou tentando entrar no meu roteador Dlink usando **C++** e estou com problemas na função login!

Eu não consigo interagir com o login e senha de forma correta!

As vezes da esse erro ou aparece o codigo `.html` da pagina do roteador falando q username ou password estão incorretos!

[image: Erro]

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>

void login(int sock) {

      char userbuf[] = "USER admin\r\n";
      char buf[3012];
      char receive_user[1024];
      char receive_pass[1024];

      memset(buf, 0, 1024);


      printf("[+] Sending Username...\n");
      send(sock, userbuf, strlen(userbuf), 0);
      recv(sock, receive_user, 200, 0);
      printf("[+] %s", receive_user);


      sprintf(buf, "PASS %s\r\n", "admin");

      send(sock, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
      recv(sock, receive_pass, 200, 0);
      printf("[+] %s", receive_pass);

}

int connect_target(char *host, u_short port)
{
    int sock = 0;
    struct hostent *hp;
    WSADATA wsa;
    struct sockaddr_in sa;

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsa);
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));

    hp = gethostbyname(host);
    if (hp == NULL) {
        printf("gethostbyname() error!\n"); exit(0);
    }
    printf("[+] Connecting to %s\n", host);
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_port = htons(port);
    sa.sin_addr = **((struct in_addr **) hp->h_addr_list);

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0)      {
        printf("[-] socket blah?\n");
        exit(0);
        }
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &sa, sizeof(sa)) < 0)
        {printf("[-] connect() blah!\n");
        exit(0);
          }
    printf("[+] Connected to %s\n", host);
    return sock;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int sock = 0;
    int data, port;
    printf("\n[$] Authentication Router Dlink\n");
    if ( argc < 2 ) { printf("Nenhum argumento"); exit(0); }
    port = 80;
    sock = connect_target(argv[1], port);
    login(sock);
    closesocket(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O erro significa que o method enviado não foi implementado. No caso você precisa enviar uma solicitação utilizando o protocolo HTTP, além do mais caso a autenticação seja basic você precisa enviar a header de autenticação basic com o valor login:senha em base64.

Comment: Vou ter que usar CGI para isso?

Comment: Você pode utilizar uma lib HTTP para facilitar a comunicação ou montar a header voce mesmo, pode começar assim: stringstream << "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n" ...